# Mobile browser bug: when top bar is visible, menu links don't work well

Tags: mobile, hyperlink, menu, overflow, responsive

For screen max-width: 479.98px menu has width: 100%; and body has class .lock {overflow: hidden;}. When menu is collapsed, class .lock is removed. It works well when I test it on small screen simulator on my PC, but on mobile I found a bug: if top bar of mobile browser is visible, there is no following the menu link, while menu collapses as it should, and I see the anchor at the url. But if browser top bar is hidden, everything works fine! And there is no problem for wider screens, with no overflow: hidden for body.

Tob bar visible, no links following. [screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDfpE.jpg)

Tob bar hidden, no problem. [screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7j9j.jpg)

Code: https://github.com/randominical/transys_demonstration

Demonstration: https://randominical.github.io/transys_demonstration/ To see the problem open it on mobile not bigger then 479px!

UPD: I'm nor sure anymore that the point is about the screen width. First of all, please test if you see the bug on your device.

Comment: Please add all of the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: I have no idea which part of code is relevant here, so I added a link to my github where anyone can see all of it